# Склонение по падежам русских словосочетаний (pyphrasy)

Tags: json, api, php

Здравствуйте!

Возникла задача изменить заголовки на сайте в родительный падеж. Долго искал бесплатное решение... и Вот нашел. http://pyphrasy.herokuapp.com/ Ребята МОЛОДЦЫ ! Работает как доктор прописал даже во множественном числе (много разных пересмотрел, - не каждый может).

У них есть еще **API** https://github.com/summerisgone/pyphrasy Вот только не могу сообразить как мне его применить у себя на сайте... точнее - он после отправки фразы выдает JSON с результатом. Просто с JSON не сталкивался ни разу, вот и думаю как мне его в переменную запихать.

Попробовал так:

```
$url_in = "http://pyphrasy.herokuapp.com/inflect?phrase=".$myroc["title"]."&cases=gent&cases=datv";
        $fp = file_get_contents($url_in);
                    if (!$fp){$title_enc = $myroc["title"];} else {
                        $title_enc = json_decode($fp);
                    }

                    echo $title_enc;
```

...при таком раскладе сервер задумывается, ответа не дождаться, что делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если проблема только с распарсиванием JSON, то вам поможет функция **[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)**.

Вот пример:

```
$phrase = urlencode('другое слово');
$url_in = "http://pyphrasy.herokuapp.com/inflect?phrase={$phrase}&cases=gent&cases=datv";

$fp = file_get_contents($url_in);
if (!$fp) {
    $title_enc = $myroc["title"];
} else {
    $title_enc = json_decode($fp, true);
}

print_r($title_enc);
# Выведет: 
# Array ( [datv] => другому слову [orig] => другое слово [gent] => другого слова )
```

Не забывайте кодировать словосочетание с помощью **[urlencode](https://php.net/urlencode)**

Comment: @VenZell Спасибо, инфа полезная но, я про другое. Мне нужно содержимое получить - лучше через file_get_contents или как по другому лучше? И странно он возвращает ответ в таком виде: \u043f\u0443\u043b\u044c\u0442\u0430\u043c и т.д.

Comment: @cheh1, я добавил пример.  
Вариант с **file_get_contents** вполне себе рабочий, так что почему нет?  
То, что вы называете ответом в странном виде, на самом деле экранированная последовательность utf-8 символов (ваше слово или словосочетание)

Comment: @VenZell спасибо, вот только почему-то с одним словом работает а со словосочетанием виснет надолго, хотя на демо странице все довольно быстро обрабатывает, словосочетания в том числе... Но это наверно тема для другого вопроса

Comment: @cheh1, обновил ответ. Проверил работу на словосочетании - все загружается очень быстро.

Comment: @VenZell Спасибо Друг - все дело в нем видимо было!